# How to solve differential equation involving commutator and anti-commutator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, commutator, density-operator, anticommutator

In one of my exercise, I got following differential equation for density matrix $\rho$,
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt}=-i[H_1,\rho]+\{H_2,\rho\}
$$
where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are the Hermitian Hamiltonian, and $[.,.]$ is commutator, and $\{.,.\}$ is anti-commutator. I know that the commutator part on the r.h.s. causes rotation to our state. I have no idea what the anti-commutator part will do. Is there any method to solve such kind of equations? Can I make some statements about the solution of $\rho$, for e.g., how will it behave (maybe at short time or at long time), etc? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to write down the commutator and the anticommutator explicitly:
$$\frac{d\rho}{dt} = (-iH_1 + H_2)\rho + \rho(iH_1+H_2).$$
Now one could already guess the solution or solve it using any of the available methods for linear matrix equations. For example, the formal solution to 
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax(t),$$
is
$$x=x(0)\exp{(At)},$$
we can now try to use variation of constant by experimenting with
$$\rho(t) = e^{-iH_1 t +H_2t}\tilde{\rho}(t)$$
and so on (being careful to preserve the order of the matrix exponents in respect to the density matrix).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "variation of constant"?

Comment: The solution looks to be of the form $\rho(t)=\exp(H^*t)\rho(0)\exp(Ht)$, where $H=H_2+iH_1$.